# if a property sample work

Tags: python, properties, descriptor

In book of "Core Python Programming", there is a sample about how to use property. The code is like this:

```
class Hidex(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    @property
    def x():
        def fget(self):
            return ~self.__x
        def fset(self, x):
            assert isinstance(val, int), 'val must be int'
            self.__x = ~x
        return locals()
```

The book says, this class will work with the following code:

```
inst = Hidex(20)
print inst.x
inst.x = 30
print inst.x
```

But I don't think this class will work. because when access inst.x, interpreter will actually run `Hidex.__dict__['x'].__get__(x, Hidex)`, and because x = property(x), the first arg 'fget' of property is x, rather than the function 'fget' defined in x().

Also, when I run this code, I got the result of:

```
{'fget': <function fset at 0x.....>, 'self': <__main__.xxxx>, 'fget': <function fget at 0x....>}
traceback:
...... # this result is just telling t.x = 30 cannot run, just skip the details
AttributeError: cannot set attribute
```

Do I miss something? why the book intend this can work?

Comment: `this code doesn't work either.` - Please explain the actual problem. Why do you think the code is not working fine?

Comment: hi @thefourtheye, I update the problem. Do u think  we can use property in suck a way like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would make sence:

```
class Hidex(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
            return ~self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, int), 'val must be int'
        self.__x = ~x
```

Looks like `@property` in the code of your question is not the builtin but a different version.

This is likely what was intended here:

```
def nested_property(func):
    """Make defining properties simpler.
    """
    names = func()
    names['doc'] = func.__doc__
    return property(**names)


class Hidex(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    @nested_property
    def x():
        def fget(self):
            return ~self.__x
        def fset(self, x):
            assert isinstance(x, int), 'val must be int'
            self.__x = ~x
        return locals()
```

Comment: thanks very much, @Mike Müller, I know this will work. My question is, the book insist the above code works, but I don't think so. And I am not sure if I miss something.

Comment: This may be the problem. If this is true, then looks like the book need to update

Comment: @Spybdai Yes. There was another copy-paste problem. It says `assert isinstance(val, int)` but it must be `x` not `val`. Guess, there is a need for unit tests for the book code examples.